# Fit UIStackView in different orientation by changing the multiplier value of the constraint

Tags: ios, swift, constraints, nslayoutconstraint, uistackview

Let me describe the situation here. I have two horizontal stacks and a vertical stack. First horizontal stack contains two circular `UIView`s, the second horizontal stack contains one circular `UIView`. I added both of two horizontal stacks into the vertical stack, when I run the program it works fine, please [see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BpyHC.png) (portrait mode) to get clear concept.

In landscape mode, I've changed it a bit, I set the `widthAnchor` of the first horizontal stack to a percentile of 0.67 and the `widthAnchor` of the second horizontal stack to a percentile of 0.33 in accordance with the display view and change the vertical stack axis to horizontal. The idea is that when I turn it into landscape mode, all stacks will fit into the display view and lined up in a single row. It works fine, please [see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BpyHC.png) (landscape mode) to get clear concept.

But the problem is when I get back to portrait mode again. It seems that they are still stuck with the previous width constraints. Something 
[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uRPRh.png).

Though I've changed the *widthAnchors*, they are not working. What am I doing wrong here? Here is my code:

```
    var firstCircleStack = circleFirstHorizontalStack.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: displayView.widthAnchor)
    var secondCircleStack = circleSecondHorizontalStack.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: displayView.widthAnchor)

    if UIScreen.main.bounds.height < UIScreen.main.bounds.width {

        // landscape mode
        circleVerticalStack.axis = .horizontal
        firstCircleStack = firstCircleStack.setMultiplier(multiplier: 0.67)
        secondCircleStack = secondCircleStack.setMultiplier(multiplier: 0.33)
    }

    else {

        // portrait mode
        circleVerticalStack.axis = .vertical
        firstCircleStack = firstCircleStack.setMultiplier(multiplier: 1)
        secondCircleStack = secondCircleStack.setMultiplier(multiplier: 1)
    }
```

To set the multiplier value I am using this:

```
extension NSLayoutConstraint {

func setMultiplier(multiplier:CGFloat) -> NSLayoutConstraint {

    let newConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(
        item: firstItem,
        attribute: firstAttribute,
        relatedBy: relation,
        toItem: secondItem,
        attribute: secondAttribute,
        multiplier: multiplier,
        constant: constant)

    newConstraint.priority = priority
    newConstraint.shouldBeArchived = self.shouldBeArchived
    newConstraint.identifier = self.identifier
    newConstraint.isActive = true
    print("new constraint multiplier \(newConstraint.multiplier)")
    NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate([self])
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([newConstraint])
    return newConstraint
}
```